# Не работает кнопка «В корзину» в самой корзине 1C Bitrix?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс

Добрый день!
Есть сайт на 1c bitrix, на нем страница корзины /personal/cart/
на этой странице появляется товар, когда нажимаешь на кнопку "В корзину"
В самой корзине есть товар, и когда я нажимаю на кнопку "В корзину", то ничего не происходит, полный 0,
Со всех остальных страниц кнопка срабатывает нормально
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

дело в том что у вас видимо корзина находится выше по коду чем компонент который добавляет товар в корзину. У этих 2 компонентов скорей всего в параметрах компонента на странице ACTION_VARIABLE одинаковые( в примере по умочанию будет action) сделайте их разными и у вас должно все заработать, если у вас не кастомизирован метод добавления в корзину.

```
  <? $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent ( "bitrix:sale.basket.basket",
    "page.cart",
    array (
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE"            => "page.cart",
        "COLUMNS_LIST"                  => array (
            0 => "NAME",
            1 => "DISCOUNT",
            2 => "WEIGHT",
            3 => "DELETE",
            4 => "DELAY",
            5 => "TYPE",
            6 => "PRICE",
            7 => "QUANTITY",
        ),
        "PATH_TO_ORDER"                 => "/cart/order/",
        "HIDE_COUPON"                   => "Y",
        "PRICE_VAT_SHOW_VALUE"          => "N",
        "COUNT_DISCOUNT_4_ALL_QUANTITY" => "Y",
        "USE_PREPAYMENT"                => "N",
        "QUANTITY_FLOAT"                => "N",
        "SET_TITLE"                     => "Y",
        "ACTION_VARIABLE"               => "action",
        "OFFERS_PROPS"                  => array (),
        "USE_GIFTS"                     => "N",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME"                => "blue"
    ),
    false
); ?>
```